# POST List with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to POST a C# List with `HTTPWebRequest`. 
I'm using the following block of code but get the

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'char[]'

```
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("My_Url");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mylist);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Don't you need to serialize your list into JSON since you're declaring your content as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation you should pass `string` or `char[]` or `char*` to [GetBytes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

You can use `LINQ`:

```
byte[] buffer = mylist.SelectMany(str => Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)).ToArray(); // use needed encoding
```